# MySQL TableAdapter in Visual Studio 2017 Primary Key issues

Tags: mysql, .net, database, primary-key, tableadapter

I have a MySQL database. I have designed my tables via HeidiSQL on my server:

[image]

You'll notice the Primary Key is defined. However, I'm having issues getting it playing nicely in Visual Studio designers - errors when I try to update db from app. If I go into the TableAdpaters>Configure>Finish, I get the following when it self-tests:

[image]

Weird thing is that in the designer view - it looks like it has discerned "ID" as some kind of key:

[image]

The create table SQL looks like this in Heidi:

[image]

I have a sneaking suspicion that my Primary Keys aren't 'fully created' via Heidi (having read something similar in a threat somewhere). Could anyone please advise how to create PKeys properly in Heigi or similar IDEs so that Visual Studio is happy?

Comment: Maybe it just doesn't like TEXT primary keys?

Comment: ^ This guy. Awesome. I'm using a type of GUID as an index (in LiteDB = ObjectId) - I changed the column type to Char(50) and all now works. I knew that laziness around not chasing down what columns to use would get me someday! Thanks man.